# Can I visit Schengen countries on a Type-D Schengen Visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, long-stay-visas

I’m going to Germany for a semester exchange and I have a long-stay visa from Germany. Can I travel to the other Schengen states during this period with this visa or do I have to apply for a separate short stay Schengen visa?

My visa is German national visa type D. It is for a duration of 4 months, i.e., longer than 90 days. It says on the visa that the long stay visa is valid in Deutschland, which is different from my earlier visa, which I had when I visited Germany earlier; that one was a short stay visa and said it was valid in Schengen Staten.

Perhaps my current visa means that I can stay in Germany for a period of longer that 90 days can visit the other Schengen states if I don’t exceed the 90 day period.

Comment: Can you clarify the exact kind of German long stay visa/permit you'll be on? (It might make a difference)

Comment: If you are staying in Germany for more than 90 days, you most probably need a residential permit in addition to the visa. If you are allowed to travel to other Schengen states both depends on the kind of residential permit and/or the kind of visa you are issued.

Comment: @Gagravarr I have a Germany National Visa.. it says on the visa it is a type D visa...

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo As I said in my reply to Gagavarr my visa is german national visa type D it is for a duration of 4 months, i.e. longer than 90 days.. it says on the visa that the long stay visa is valid in Deutschland, which is different from my earlier visa, which I had when I visited Germany earlier, that one was a short stay visa and said it was valid in schengen staten.. so I'm wondering if what my current visa means is that I can stay in Germany for a period of longer that 90 days but I should be able to visit the other schengen states if I don't exceed the 90 day period..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When it comes to traveling within the Schengen area, a type D visa is equivalent to a regular residential permit. You are basically allowed to visit other Schengen countries for up to 90 days within a 180 day period.

There are some caveats - you must carry your passport or equivalent travel documents, be able to document the purpose of your visit (going on holiday should be enough), document your ability to finance the trip, be of no danger to national security or public health and not have been specifically expelled from the country you are traveling to. Since there is no immigration control on the borders between Schengen states, these requirements are in most cases rather theoretical. If however you should be checked, you probably save a lot of hassle if you have the required documentation handy.

Comment: @Szabolcs The right to visit other Schengen countries for 90 days within a 180 day period with a residence permit or national D visa is set in EU regulation 2016/399, article 6 1(b). A single-entry visa does not 'allow its holder to travel in and out of this Schengen country as he/she pleases'.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Sorry about deleting the comments, I thought you haven't seen them yet.  It turned out that I was given inaccurate information and it was in fact a multiple entry visa. I also found regulation 265/2010 (not the same you mention) which further confirmed your answer.  Thus I deleted the comments.

Answer (score 7):

As per German visa regulations published by the German Foreign Office (scroll down the link):

> As a result of Regulation 265/2010 it is now possible for anyone in
>   possession of a national visa (D visa) and a valid travel document to
>   move freely in the Schengen area up to three months in any six‑month
>   period.

https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/visabestimmungen-node

Answer (score 7):

As others suggested, you are allowed to travel in other Schengen states while complying with the 90/180 rule.  This is also stated on the [site](http://www.msz.gov.pl/en/travel_to_poland/visa/) of Poland Ministry of Foreign Affairs:

> The national D-type visa entitles the holder to:
>
> - stay in the territory of Poland throughout the period of its validity;
> - additionally move within the territory of other Schengen states for up to three months within a half-year period.

Comment: The question is about Germany, although the rules are the same. Curious why you answered for Poland?