# Can I visit all the countries in the Schengen area with a national visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, russian-citizens, long-stay-visas

I'm an exchange student from Russia, and I have the national visa D type. But it's written there "valid for Italia". Can I go to other Schengen countries with this kind of visa? Because I want to visit France but I don't know if I can. Now I'm in Italy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I visit Schengen countries on a long term German Visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19147/can-i-visit-schengen-countries-on-a-long-term-german-visa)

Comment: @Ksenia - "valid for Italia" means that you need to enter and leave Schengen zone through Italia. Once you are in the zone, you can freely travel to any Schengen country. Just make sure that your flight back to Russia initiates from Italy.

Comment: @Andrey that is not correct.  The holder of a type D visa may enter at (and depart from) any point.

Comment: @phoog - yes and no. You "can" enter Schengen thru any country of the zone, but usually the rules (that each country defines) day that you need to spending most of the Schengen zone time in the country using the Visa. Like for Finland, you need to enter the zone via Finland at least 50% time etc. If you break those rules you may have problems getting a new visa. That's what i meant, but probably explained poorly above

Comment: @Andrey do you have a source for that Finnish rule?  It doesn't make any sense.  For example, suppose someone lives in a place that has no direct flights to Finland.  Is such a person restricted from being able to fly witha Schengen-based airline?  Surely the point of Schengen visa rules isnot to drive business away from Schengen companies.

Comment: @phoog - a friend of mine who lives in Russia was doing a Finnish Schengen visa and he was told that it's the rules. Another friend who also lives in Russia was denied his Finnish Schengen visa because he has always used it for other countries and only visited Finland once. But i can't find anything concrete online right now

Comment: @Andrey I could see that they might apply such a rule to Russians (since I assume there are plenty of direct flights between the countries in addition to the land border).  I wonder what would happen to someone who lived in, say, east Africa, who needed to fly to Finland regularly but did so through western Europe.  If such a rule is indeed applied selectively to Russian or former Soviet travelers, I'd also be unsurprised if it were not published anywhere.

Comment: @phoog - it's really more about where you spend the most time, not as much port of first entry. If you got Finnish via, then it's implied that you should be spending the majority of Schengen time in Finland.

Answer (score 6):

According the [Italian Ministry of Foreign affairs](http://www.esteri.it/MAE/EN/Ministero/Servizi/Stranieri/IngressoSoggiornoInItalia/Visto_ingresso/Tipologie_visto_durata.htm) you can visit other countries in Schengen area as long as it no more then 90 days in a 6 months period :

> Long sojourn or "national" Visas (NV), which are only valid for visits that are longer than 90 days (type D), with one or more entries, in the territory of the Schengen State whose diplomatic mission issued the visa. Holders of type D visas are permitted to circulate freely in Schengen countries other than the issuing one for a period of not more than 90 days per half-year and only if the visa is valid.

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect. It's obviously true that type D visas generally allow the holder to travel in the Schengen area (which is the point of this paragraph) but it still should say so on the visa.

Comment: You should also be aware that they have no way to check that you are sticking to the 90 day rule, so in practice you have unlimited travel within Schengen for the duration of your visa.

Comment: @Annoyed [Estonia](http://www.vm.ee/?q=en/node/9232), [France](http://www.consulfrance-losangeles.org/spip.php?article799), [Poland](http://www.msz.gov.pl/en/travel_to_poland/visa/), and finally [Regulation 265/2010](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2010:085:0001:0004:EN:PDF) which requires long-stay visa to be equated for travel purposes to residence permit (item 3), see also Article I paragraph 2 the amendments to the aquis.

Comment: @Karlson What does any of this have to do with my remark?

Comment: @Annoyed There is no requirement for territorial validity in accordance with the Regulation I linked.

Comment: @Karlson Maybe, I don't think I wrote anything about that either. Did you check the link I provided in my answer? Did I misinterpret something? Or are you saying it's not current anymore?

Comment: @Annoyed Link in [English](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/what-does-my-sticker-visa-mean) would have been better.  The information may still be valid for other types of visas, C, A, but not for D, which is equated in travel information to the residence permit.

Comment: @Karlson I just noticed I still have a downvote locked in on this answer, if you would edit it, I would remove it.

Comment: @annoyed it is done...