# Can a Hungarian work permit holder apply to Finland for a Schengen business visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, hungary, finland

I have a Hungarian work permit (with 1 year validity) but haven't traveled yet to Hungary. I have to wait 3 more months to go to Hungary due to delays in the work agreement with the client.

Now I have another opportunity to travel to Finland for a shorter period (20 days) and applied for a Schengen visa at the VFS center.

Can Finland cancel my Hungarian work permit in order to grant the Schengen business visa, or will I keep the work permit? What is the procedure in such cases?

Comment: What is the start date of your Hungarian work permit?

Comment: January 2018 is the start date of my Hungary Work permit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With National Visa D for Hungary, can I stay a couple of days in another Schengen country before arriving Hungary?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25288/with-national-visa-d-for-hungary-can-i-stay-a-couple-of-days-in-another-schenge)

Comment: Its not the exact case. My question is whether applying for business visa(Schengen visa) to Finland affects my existing Hungarian work permit or not?, Can they cancel it before issuing the Schengen Visa for Finland

Comment: Who are "they"? Finland cannot cancel Hungarian work permit but can reject you a visa because you already have one Schengen visa for the same time.

Answer (score 1):

With a valid Hungarian D visa you can enter Finland directly.

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines, regarding **Finland**:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a valid D visa issued by another Schengen
>     Member State for a maximum stay of 90 days.

Comment: As per my analysis, In order to travel other schengen countries the person should stay(atleast a shorter period) in the country where the work permit is issued. In this case I have Hungarian work permit and I cannot travel Finland directly as  I have not obtained the resident card from Hungary. So I have applied for Schengen business visa to Finland. Is it required to cancel the existing Hungarian work permit to obtain the Finland Schengen visa? This is the question!!

Comment: @James Do you have a Hungarian Long-stay (D) visa? If you do, you can fly to Finland directly, period. If you don't have it, please upload a copy of your work Permit (blacking out personal Details)

Comment: I have Hungarian Work permit D visa (1 year), where can i upload the file?

Comment: @James It's OK. With a valid D visa you **can** enter Finland directly, and whoever told you otherwise is wrong.

Comment: How long I can stay in Finland with Hungary D visa

Comment: @James Up to 90 days, like says in the quote

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted Finland Embassy and got confirmation that, it is not possible to apply for another schengen visa when the person is holding a work permit from any schengen area. But the person can travel Schengen countries only after reaching Hungary and immigration formalities are completed from there.

Comment: "But the person can travel Schengen countries only after reaching Hungary and immigration formalities are completed from there." That's absolutely wrong, and if the person who said that is an embassy employee, they ought to be fired. You have a valid D visa from a Schengen state, thus you can enter Finland directly.