# Traveling to Germany with a French study visa

Tags: visas, schengen, long-stay-visas

Say that someone has a French visa for study purposes. If he wants to travel to Germany by train for instance, can he go there freely without a passport or visa check?

Comment: You can visit other Schengen countries legally for up to 90 days, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19147/can-i-visit-schengen-countries-on-a-long-term-german-visa Furthermore, there shouldn't be any *systematic* check on the border, so your passport and visa won't be checked in most cases. However, border or not, occasional ID checks are always possible, especially in France but also in Germany I believe. As it's an internal border, your passport shouldn't be stamped, even if there is a control.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, if you have a long term visa from one of the Schengen countries you can freely move to any other Schengen country and stay for a period of three months or less in any 6 months period ([90/180 rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule)).

From [EU Immigration Portal](http://ec.europa.eu/immigration/tab1.do?subSec=30&language=7$en#morethan):

> When you stay in an EU country for a long stay, usually for more than three months, you will generally be issued with a national long-stay visa and/or a residence permit.
>
> If your long-stay visa or permit has been issued by a Schengen area country, you can travel to another Schengen area country for three months per six-month period

Comment: Technically, that's not exactly what was asked.