# Re-entering Europe with a French "long séjour" visa

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, france

I am a national from Mexico, currently an exchange student following a program in France and have a "long séjour" residence permit (multiple entry visa). During the summer holidays, I plan to travel outside Europe, and then I will return to Europe to continue my studies but I want to enter from Spain (my French visa will be still valid). Will this cause any trouble? Or do I need to re-enter Europe on the country that issued my visa (i.e. France)?

Also, is any visa issued from any Schengen country considered as a "Schengen visa"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant legal texts do not, as far as I know, give any specific meaning to the term “Schengen visa”. A regular Schengen visa for short stays is called “uniform visa” because the rules are the same in the whole Schengen area. A long-stay visa is not a Schengen visa in the sense that the requirements and procedure to obtain one are not laid out in the Schengen visa code but you [can enter through Spain or visit other countries in the Schengen area](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19147/can-i-visit-schengen-countries-on-a-long-term-german-visa) with a regular French long-stay visa.