# Travel in Schengen countries on Visa Valid for Deutschland and Type D

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, long-stay-visas

I have Visa which i got from German Embassy in India. it says

Valid for : **Deutschland**, Type of Visa: **D**, Number of entries: **MULT**, Valid for Stay: **90**, 6 months Visa.

**I have not traveled on this Visa before.** mean I never stayed in Germany on this visa, my concern is, do I need to stay there for some time before travelling to other countries. Or is it OK to travel?

Now I need to visit 2-3 Schengen countries for tourism purpose. So in my expected travel, transit is from Munich.

Can I travel on this Visa to Paris, Belgium and Vienna?

Comment: @Karlson the visa in this question is not a long term visa.

Comment: @phoog The visa in the question I linked is the national visa Type D issued by Germany.  What's the difference here?  That the previous question the visa was issued for a period longer then 90 days?

Comment: @phoog The questions are indeed duplicates since the visa type is the same, regardless of authorised length of stay. I modified the title of the duplicate question to reflect this.

Comment: @Karlson frankly I am confused.  The D visa is a long term visa category but it has been issued for a short duration of stay.  I think that additional wrinkle is enough to warrant a separate question.

Comment: @phoog That may be.  But the only real difference I see in the issuance of C vs. D is potential for employment even a temporary one.

Comment: @Karlson doesn't the "valid for Deutschland" notation make this a limited territorial validity visa?

Comment: @phoog Same as the other question.

Comment: Guys, my actual concern is.. i never stayed in Germany on this Visa. so is there any restriction that firstly i need to stay there or enter there ... , then travel to other schengen. In my forthcoming travel i will just transit through Germany.

Comment: @Techmaster, have you read the other Question and its answers? If so, **and it doesn't answer what you want to know**, then please **edit this original question** to contain a request for what you _really want to know_, because what you're actually asking is already answered there.

Comment: On what basis did you get this visa? What does it say under “Anmerkungen/Remarques/Remarks”?

Comment: Anmerkungen/Remarques/Remarks = mit bedingungen/auflagen versehen

Answer (score 1):

What you got is a long-stay visa so you can indeed travel to other Schengen countries as explained in [Can I visit Schengen countries on a Type-D Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19147/can-i-visit-schengen-countries-on-a-type-d-german-visa)

As far as Belgium, France, etc. are concerned you have the right to stay there for up to 90 days and in most cases you won't even see any border guards when travelling between these countries and Germany.

But you got this visa for a reason and German border guards will probably ask about your plans when entering Germany. If you got a visa, e.g. for studies, and your first trip is purely for tourism, you might get in trouble with them.