# Travel to France from Non-EU countries with a Dutch residence permit?

Tags: schengen, international-travel, netherlands, residency

I'm not a EU citizen but holding a Dutch residence permit which allows me to travel within Schengen countries. But I'm wondering, instead of traveling from one Schengen country to another, is it also possible to travel to any Schengen country from a non-EU country with the Dutch residence permit?

Or do I have to go to Netherlands first, and then travel to another Schengen country?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to France directly. While [German national visa (Type D), but entry through another Schengen country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48760/german-national-visa-type-d-but-entry-through-another-schengen-country) deals with a long-stay visa, the rules detailed there fully apply to residence permits as well.