# Travelling while Switzerland Residence Permit is processing?

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland, long-stay-visas

I have a question pertaining to the residence permit/long-stay visa.So, I will be going to Switzerland for 5 months & have been issued with a Visa 'D' (multiple entry) for that purpose.

From what I understand on Switzerland's process, the visa grants me entry & is a prerequisite of sorts for the Residence Permit. I understand that we can travel with the residence permit. However, how about the time while it's processing (i.e. from my reporting to the Cantonal authorities to my receiving said permit).

If I wish to leave Switzerland (to other Schengen/Non-schengen) am I allowed to do so? seeing that I haven't had my residence permit yet though the visa 'D' is multiple entry. Because at that time the visa would not have been 'superseded' by the residence permit seeing that I have not gotten it.

Edit: I'm a non-EU national and I need a visa for practically every country

Comment: What canton do you live in? So I can link teh proper source?

Comment: I will be in the canton of Vaud, Lausanne :) @Crazydre

Comment: I missed the fact that your visa is multiple-entry. This makes it easier. Could you please upload an image of it just in case (blacking out personal Details)?

Comment: @Crazydre uploaded visa :)

Comment: Related http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48760/german-national-visa-type-d-but-entry-through-another-schengen-country

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I wish to leave Swtizerland (to other Schengen/Non-schengen) am I
>   allowed to do so?

Since you have multiple entry Suisse visa type "D", you are entitled to visit Schengen area and can visit upto 90 days in any 180 day period as long as your Swiss type D visa is valid:

Answer is from official [State Secretariat For Migration.](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/themen/einreise/faq.html#2)

"I have a Type D visa containing an entry saying "Suisse". Does this visa authorise me to travel around in the Schengen area?

On 5 April 2010, Type C and Type D visas were given parity of treatment as far as freedom to travel within the Schengen area for up to 90 days in any 180-day period is concerned."

Further to your question regarding travel to non Schengen countries but EU countries:

Please note EU countries like Romania, Bulgaria, Croatia and Cyprus also allow ​the holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national visas or residence permits issued by Schengen Member States visa free access provided they have a valid type C and D visas in their passport.

However EU countries like UK and Ireland are not part of Schengen, Also you would need a proper visa to visit those countries.

Comment: The [FAQs on EU website](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf) also say that Type-D visa holders can visit other states as long as they respect the 90/180 rule.